# How to set snmp trap threshold

Tags: monitoring, snmp, juniper, net-snmp

I want to monitor some firewall devices by snmp.
Now, I can get cpu info of device by snmp4j.
 But I have no idea how to use snmp trap to get specified warning and error messages from device. 
How to set CPU threshold so that a trap message will be sent according to that. 
For example, CPU usage above 70%, a trap message should be sent to manager PC. 
Should I set this threshold on every firewall device by command or implement it by snmp4j?
  I am confused, please give me some suggesions. 
Thanks in advance.